# How to allow app only for screen 4.65", 4.7", 7" and 10"

Tags: android, screen

Following the graphic below from [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[image]

I'm using the following code trying to support Tablets (7", 10") and phones with 4.65" and 4.7" screens, but the truth is that only tablets can download my app. When I try to download it from my Samsung GT-I9505 it's says not compatible.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

[image]

Comment: density of the screen matters more than the size of screen.Samsung GT-I9505 may have big screen but not having density of 600dpi.

Comment: Hi @Victor, did you find a solution to your specific width in inches? I still don't see from all of the documentation links provided how to convert all the minimum dp values into something that is clearly in inches, like what is 4.65" in minimum dp? Thanks if you know.

Comment: @Noni try android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is canonical one to support tablets only.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps

Screen width 600dp means a 7" tablet. Device independent pixels (dp) are not equal to actual screen pixels. Typical handset screen has a smallestWidth of 320dp. See also documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest

Answer (score 3):

the error is

> android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"

, to support the devices you mention, you should try to remove that or at least set it to

> android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="480"

Comment: Why? If 4.65" and 4.7" is shown as 720x1280 and 1280x720 respectively. Samsung GT-I9505 it's not 4.7"??